# Prove that the decimal part of square root of two natural numbers are equal only if both are complete squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the decimal part of the square root of two natural numbers are equal only if both are complete squares

I tried to use simple idea like $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ and... but I got nowhere

Comment: I think there's something missing from your question. After all, the decimal parts of any two natural numbers is 0 regardless of whether they're squares.

Comment: The decimal parts of the *square roots* of two natural numbers, maybe?

Comment: @ConMan question edited , I am so sorry I missed 1 word

Comment: @MishaLavrov exactly

Comment: Rick, I have no idea what you're trying to convey. At this point, I'm deleting my solution and moving on.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the statement is false.  Let the square roots in question be $n+a$ and $m+a$, where $n\neq m$, $n$ and $m$ are integers, and $0<a<1$. Then $$(n+a)^2-(m+a)^2$$ is the difference of two integers, so it is integral.

Expand $(n+a)^2-(m+a)^2$ and conclude that $a$ is rational.  Do you see why this is absurd?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a,b$ are distinct nonnegative integers such that $\sqrt{a}\;$and $\sqrt{b}\;$ have the same decimal part.

**Claim:**$\;a,b$ are both perfect squares.

**Proof:**

Initiating a proof by contradiction, assume $a,b$ are not both perfect squares.

Then at least one of $a,b$, say $a$, is not a perfect square.

- Since $a$ is a nonnegative integer but not a perfect square, it follows that $\sqrt{a}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.$\\[4pt]$

  Since $a,b$ are distinct nonnegative integers such that $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ have the same decimal part, it follows that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Z}{\,\setminus}\{0\}$, hence also $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Q}{\,\setminus}\{0\}$.

Then
\begin{align*}
&
\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Q}{\,\setminus}\{0\}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\in\mathbb{Q}{\,\setminus}\{0\}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a-2\sqrt{ab}+b\in\mathbb{Q}{\,\setminus}\{0\}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\sqrt{ab}\in\mathbb{Q}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
a-\sqrt{ab}\in\mathbb{Q}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\sqrt{a}\,\bigl(\!\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\,\bigr)\in\mathbb{Q}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\sqrt{a}\in\mathbb{Q}\;\;\;\Bigl(\text{Since $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{Q}{\,\setminus}\{0\}$}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.